# Best approach (if any possible) in windows for getting live screen image

Tags: java, c++, windows, image, graphics

I want to capture the frame currently in display on the screen of a windows pc regardless of what is being displayed as a bitmap or image file or similar.

Until now I used the Java robot API and some C++ api, however it can capture only the desktop and windows etc. but cannot capture anything that's being drawn using an overlay like videos or directX games.

Capturing while a video playing returns a image with video region black and when in game it returns image of desktop as game isn't running!

Is there any standard method for capturing everything on the screen (like in fraps etc.)?

or I need to make a custom driver for each graphics card (Impossible)

Comment: That's because the overlay is a different layer that you don't have access to from the regular screen capture interface. As far as I know, there is no (simple) way to fetch this data. You need special interfaces to the graphics card (assuming it's possible to get at all).

Comment: Yeah that's the same I heard but I was wondering if there is still something simple way we don't know yet

Answer (score 0):

The following is the code for capturing screenshots from Java:
http://www.codinguide.com/2010/04/capture-screen-shot-from-java.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: The OP clearly states that they've been using `Robot` already, so no, I doubt this will help much

Comment: Yeah that api is just for capturing desktop and open windows not any overlay style graphics